# Substitute values with their mean in a data frame in R

Tags: r

I need to replace the values of the two replica (A and B) in a data frame, with their mean.

This is the data frame:

```
Sample.Name <- c("sample01","sample01","sample02","sample02","sample03","sample03")
Rep <- c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B")
Rep <- as.factor(Rep)
joy <- sample(1000:50000000, size=120, replace=TRUE)
values <- matrix(joy, nrow=6, ncol=20)
df.data <- cbind.data.frame(Sample.Name, Rep, values)
names(df.data)[-c(1:2)] <- paste("V", 1:20, sep="")
```

And this is the loop I tried to write to substitute the mean to the replica:

```
Sample <- as.factor(Sample.Name)
livelli <- levels(Sample)
for (i in (1:(length(livelli)))){
    estrai.replica <- which(df.data == livelli[i])
    media.replica <- apply(values[estrai.replica,], 2, mean)
    foo <- rbind(media.replica)
}
```

The main problems are:

1. in this way I have only the last row in my new data frame (foo), and
2. I haven't the name of the sample in any column.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to `aggregate` your data frame. Try this:

```
aggregate(df.data, by=list(Sample.Name), FUN=mean)
```

Answer (score 2):

Out of curiosity I tried a tapply based solution.

```
# Not correct: lapply(df.data[-(1:3)], tapply, INDEX=df.data$Sample.Name, FUN=mean)
```

It just needed `as.data.frame` to "clean it up".

```
# Not correct: as.data.frame(lapply(df.data[-(1:3)], tapply, INDEX=df.data$Sample.Name, FUN=mean))
```

EDIT: Like @daroczig I got an error complaining that the trim argument to mean.default is not of length 1. So adding further arguments form mean was attempted but only when I also changed to a two argument version of "[" did I succeed in satisfying the interpreter but still not getting the right grouping of the function application. This version does work:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(df.data[, 3:22], 
                       function(x) tapply(x, df.data$Sample.Name, FUN=mean))  )
```

Comment: That is cool @DWin, good thought-provoking (+1)! Somehow I run into errors while running your code, I could make it run by calling `tapply` in an internal function, like: `as.data.frame(lapply(df.data[,-c(1:3)], function(x) tapply(x, INDEX=df.data$Sample.Name, FUN=mean)))`

Comment: I think I must have had another package loaded that added functionality. I too get an error in a different session complaining about "trim" not being of length one. I will see what I can deduce.

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` solution for time and memory efficiency

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df.data)
DT[,lapply(.SD, mean),by = Sample.Name, .SDcols = paste0('V',1:20)]
```

Note that `.SD` is the subset for each group and `.SDcols` defines the columns in `.SD` to evaluate `lapply`  upon.